# Can particle と be used with 分かる?

Tags: grammar, particle-と

Back to basics. Sometimes I see something that undoes everything I think I know.

> 私はあなたがいつも忙しい**ことを**分かっています。
>   私はあなたがいつも忙しい**と**分かっています。
>   I know that you are always busy.

Which of the above is correct? I have seen several instances of 分かる used with と, but I'm confused because nothing is being quoted, either directly or indirectly when using this verb.

When/is it ever correct to use と分かっています if there isn't an implied verb like 思う/言う etc. in between.

Comment: @naruto beat me to it so I'll just give some examples from dictionaries (to confirm it's grammatically correct): 「だめだ**と分かっ**ていながら」（広辞苑）; 「私はそれが良いことでない**と分かっ**ている。」 「私はもっと英語を話す事が必要だ**と分かっ**ている。」([Weblio 例文辞典](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E3%81%A8%E5%88%86%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%22))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 私はあなたがいつも忙しいことを分かっています。
>   私はあなたがいつも忙しいと分かっています。

Grammatically speaking, both are perfectly correct. The quotative particle と can be used with many verbs like 知る, 分かる, 見なす, 認識する and 捉える. Another simpler example:

> 高いことを知っていて買った。
>   高いと知っていて買った。
>   I bought it knowing it's expensive.

In ordinary conversations, perhaps people prefer ～と simply because it's shorter. ～ことを is preferred in formal or complicated sentences. And you can omit 私は and topicalize the nominalized こと-part instead:

> あなたがいつも忙しいことは分かっています。

Answer (score 2):

> 私はあなたがいつも忙しいことを分かっています。
> 私はあなたがいつも忙しいと分かっています。

I don't really know why but what I really feel natural is either

> 私はあなた**は**忙しい**のだということは**分かっています。
> 私はあなた**が**忙しい**ことは**分かっています。

However, sometimes or some of us would omit things in spoken language. I'm sensing though that more people shorten to only と, for example, instead of という, and I myself feel somewhat uneasy with these expressions.

---

[Edit to add]

分かる is, by the way, one of some verbs that take が to indicate the theme, and, in this case, the theme is the object of the verb, 分かる.

We don't say <strike>ものごとを分かる</strike>, though we say ものごと**を理解する.**
There are some verbs that takes が to indicate the object; 計算**ができる**, 海**が好き**, etc. For some of them, を is barely acceptable, but が sounds just the right instead.

> 「物のよしあし**が**分かる」「言わんとすること**は**よく分かる」「訳**が**分からない」
> 「身元**が**分かる」「答え**が**分かる」「持ち主**の**分からない荷物」
> 「話**の**分かる人」
> （[分かる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/237767/meaning/m1u/%E5%88%86%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B/) | デジタル大辞泉）
>
> **１-2** 希望・好悪・能力などの対象を示す。「水**が飲みたい**」「紅茶**が好きだ**」「中国語**が話せる**」
> （[が](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/34931/meaning/m1u/%E3%81%8C/) | 同上）