# How is と used in these sentences?

Tags: grammar, usage, nuances, particle-と

I have some sentences that involve the usage of と that I still don't understand:

[1.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/51660/can-particle-%E3%81%A8-be-used-with-%E5%88%86%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B/51678) This is from another user's post

> 私はあなたがいつも忙しい**と**分かっています。

[2.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57022/why-is-%E3%81%84%E3%81%A4%E3%82%82-used-in-this-sentence) My previous question

> いつも**と**変えてたまに外で食事しよう。

---

At the very basic level, this [post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15363/confusion-with-japanese-particle-%E3%81%A8-in-its-multiple-uses) pretty much sums up what I understand about と. I added a few more usages based on what I learnt so far.

- Quotation or defining particle

> e.g. [X]は日本語でなん**と**言いますか？How do you say [X] in Japanese?
>
> e.g. 日本語は難しい**と**思います。(I) think Japanese is difficult.
>
> e.g. 彼は明日来る**と**言った｡ He said that he will come tomorrow.

- Conditional particle

> e.g. 彼は暇だ**と**いつもゲームをしているの。If he is free, he always plays games.

- List of things

> e.g. ナイフ**と**フォークでステーキを食べた。(I) ate steak with a knife and fork.

- With/Partner of interaction/Accompaniment

> e.g. 友達**と**映画に行った｡(I) went to watch a movie with my friend.
>
> e.g. 父**と**似ている。(I) resemble my father.

- Objects of similarity/difference

> e.g. 私の意見は彼の意見**と**異なる。My opinion is different from everyone.
>
> e.g. いつも**と**同じ電車です。(It) is the same train as usual.

- Sound/Onomatopoeia

> e.g. 星がきらきら**と**輝いている｡The stars are twinkling.

I understand there are many more uses of と that I did not include in the list and that I may not be aware of.

---

I have trouble connecting both of the sentences above into one of the listed categories.

But if I had to guess, と under sentence 1 is used as a Quotation or defining particle? Such as the second example 日本語は難しいと思います。

And for sentence 2, I see it used like いつもと同じ電車です under Objects of similarity/difference.

But I'm confused here because 変える is not a "similarity" but a "change from usual". However, I might have a misconception that と is not just used for objects of similarity or differences in this particular case.

Can someone explain how と is used in each of the sentences above?
I would appreciate similar examples like ones provided above to help me understand how と is used in these cases, and I'm really thankful to anyone who can help clear up my confusion with this particle.

Comment: How is と変えて not expressing a difference?

Comment: @mamster So far I've only encountered examples that uses と in cases like "A is not the same as B" and that's what I thought "difference" meant e.g. と違う. In this sentence, と変える seemed more like "change from A to B" to me. But maybe definition of "difference" is much broader than what I thought, I would like to know some similar examples. Like can you use と終わる, と始める etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for your first sentence, you're right that the と is a quotative particle.
It's often used with a verb that introduces one's utterance or thought, e.g. 言う, 思う, 感じる, 知る, 分かる, 話す, etc.

A few examples:

> 嫌だ**と言う**
>   危ない**と感じる**
>   やめよう**と思った**
>   痛い**と**顔をしかめる <sub>(「言って」「思って」 etc. are occasionally left out)</sub>
>   これが最後**と**別れを惜しむ
>   (examples above taken from 明鏡国語辞典)
>   正しい**という**結論に達する
>   (from [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/154670/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A8/))

---

As for your second sentence, you're right again that the と indicates 「比較・類別の際に照合される相手」(明鏡国語辞典) , 「比較の基準」([デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/154670/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A8/)), or "Object of Similarity/Difference" in your list.
The と is often used with a verb or adjective that expresses difference, change, similarity, identity (sameness), or comparison, e.g. 同じ, 違う, 異なる, 似る, 比べる, etc. and it functions like "(same) as..." "(different/differentiate) from..." "(similar) to..." "(compare) with...". In your example, ～と変える is used to mean "change from...". <sub>(～と変える can also mean "change into~~" (≂～に変える) depending on context, and the と here indicates 動作の結果. By the way, ～と[代]{か}える/[替]{か}える can mean "exchange for~~/replace with~~", where the と indicates 動作の対象.)</sub>

A few examples:

> あなた**と同じ**考えだ
>   以前**と**は条件が**異なる**
>   父[子]は子[父]**と似ている**
>   (examples taken from 明鏡国語辞典)
>   君の**と**は**比べものにならない**
>   昔**と違う**
>   (from [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/154670/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A8/))

---

By the way, the example `父と似ている。(I) resemble my father` is categorized in `With/Partner of interaction/Accompaniment` in your list, but I think it should fall under `Objects of similarity/difference`.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. 私はあなたがいつも忙しいと分かっています。

Question A:

> と under sentence 1 is used as a Quotation or defining particle? Such as the second example 日本語は難しいと思います。

Yes, it is.
I'll show you the reason.
日本語は難しいと思います could be rewritten as:
(a)「日本語は難しい」**と**思います。
Sentence 1 could be rewritten as:
(b)「あなたがいつも忙しい」**と**私は分かっています。
と in (a) and (b) has the same function as quotation or defining particle.

> 2. いつもと変えてたまに外で食事しよう。

Question B:

> と is not just used for objects of similarity or differences in this particular case.

と in 2 is not used for objects of similarity or differences.
Why do you have the idea that と in 2 is like that in 私の意見は彼の意見**と**異なる or that in いつも**と**同じ電車です?
There is no such suggestions in the answers [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/57022/why-is-%E3%81%84%E3%81%A4%E3%82%82-used-in-this-sentence).
I think いつもと(変える) in 2 means "(change) from a usual manner/custom".
Anyway some words are omitted in 2, so the omission might make you confused.
The full text of 2 might be like:
- いつも**の習慣{しゅうかん}**/**やり方｛かた｝** と変えてたまに外で食事しよう。
- いつも**家｛いえ｝で食｛た｝べるという習慣｛しゅうかん｝** と変えてたまに外で食事しよう。

Comment: I've never learned that usage of と to indicate change from a past habit. It doesn't fit into any of the categories I listed above? Are there other verbs that take similar forms and can be used with と to indicate change for example?

Comment: @Shade549: >Are there other verbs that take similar forms and can be used with と: いつも（のやり方）と違{たが}えて; いつも（のやり方）と間違{まちが}えて; いつも（のやり方）と異{こと}なって.