# Why is the particle と being used in the following sentences?

Tags: usage, particle-と

I'm reading the JLPT N3 読む guide and the explanation for the conjunction ただ says this:

> 前の文の内容**と**違うことがある**と**付け加えて説明する。

Also, there's a section where the next sentence appears:

> 台風が接近しています。そのため、明日の旅行は中止**と**なりました．

Why is と being used for this?

Answer (score 3):

> 前の文の内容**と**違うことがある...

「～～**と**違う」 means "is different **from** ~~".

The と in ～と違う indicates 「比較・類別の際に照合される相手」(明鏡国語辞典) or 「比較の基準」([#3 in デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/154670/meaning/m0u/)). 
It's used with a word that expresses difference, similarity, identity, or comparison, such as 同じ, 違う, 異なる, 似る, 比べる, etc. Eg:

> ～**と**同じ -- is same **as**~~
>   ～**と**異なる -- differs **from**~~
>   ～**と**似ている -- is similar **to**~~
>   ～**と**比べる -- compare **with**~~

Related thread: [How is と used in these sentences?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57038/9831)

---

The と in ～と付け加えて説明する is quotative.

> 『前の文の内容と違うことがある』**と**付け加えて説明する。
>   *lit.* (The word ただ is used to) additionally explain **that** there's something different from (something that deviates from / doesn't agree with) the content of the previous sentence.

---

> 明日の旅行は中止**と**なりました。

～～となる (≂ ～～になる) means "become ~~." The と marks the result of change.

中止となりました means *lit.* "became cancellation" → "was cancelled"

<sub>Your example can be rephrased as 明日の旅行は中止になりました without changing the meaning. 中止**と**なりました sounds a bit more formal than 中止**に**なりました.</sub>

～となる and ～になる are not always interchangeable. For more, see: [What is the difference between 〜となる and 〜になる?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/739/9831)

Answer (score 1):

前の文の内容と - With the content of the previous sentence

**Noun +　と - with(noun)**

**友達と - with friend**

違うことがあると - If there is a difference

**jisho + と - if(verb)**

**そこに行くとーIf you go there**

付け加えて説明する - Add explanation

前の文の内容と違うことがあると付け加えて説明する。

literally it means

If there is a difference  With the content of the previous sentence Add explanation

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: regarding your second question only (please consider splitting your question in two different ones).**

The following patterns are very similar an both mean "A becomes B":

> Aは B**に**なる
>
> Aは B**と**なる

The difference between them is that 「AはB**と**なる」 implies that **B is the final state reached by A**, whereas 「AはB**に**なる」 does not.

For example:

> 昔はこの辺に畑がたくさんあったものだが、今はすっかり住宅地【じゅうたくち】**と**なった。 Long ago, there were plenty of fields in this area. Now, it has completely turned into a residential district.

It is very unlikely that the area changes to a different kind of place in the future, therefore it is its final state and となる is used.

Similarly, in the sentence of the question

> 明日の旅行は中止**と**なりました。 The trip tomorrow has been cancelled.

the trip has been cancelled。Since 「**と**なる」 is used, we can infer that the possibility of uncancel the trip is very unlikely as "cancelled" is regarded as the final state of the trip.

Comment: @Kaskade, this is the reason why we don't say 「春となる」: since more seasons will keep coming, spring can't be the final state at all.

Comment: `「AはBになると￥」...「AはBになるに」` <--  You meant to type 「AはBとなる」「AはBになる」?  `なると is used.` <-- You mean となる?

Comment: @Chocolate, yes, you are absolutely right, I mistyped it. Thank you!