# Is the following と an example of 'with' or 'compared to'?

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of **と** in [私はお金持ちになったとしても、今**と**変わらない生活をするでしょう。]?

that **と** doesn't seem to be a 'connotation' particle. It rather seems like a 'comparison' particle.

English translation:[Even if I were to become rich, I doubt my life would change much from what it is like now.]
Japanese version:[私はお金持ちになったとしても、今**と**変わらない生活をするでしょう。].

Comment: It's basically the same thing as と同じ or と違う, I think

Comment: @AeonAkechi could you explain how と同じ and と違う function?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57038/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/71742/9831

Comment: While I personally feel kandyman's answer / chocolate's links have answered your question sufficiently, if you're looking for a dictionary definition [look at #3 here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A8/#jn-154670).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the functions of と is to highlight a relationship between a noun phrase with the subject of a clause. This is often used in comparisons. It's similar to the English word 'as' in this sense. For example:

> この車は僕の**と**同じです。This car is the same **as** my car.

Here, the と serves to show that the subject (この車) has a relationship with the other noun phrase (僕の車). That relationship is then clarified (同じです). It's like saying `the relationship between Noun A and Noun B is X`.

Similarly, in your sentence 今と変わらない生活, the subject is inferred as the lifestyle of 私はお金持ちになった and と indicates a relationship between that and 今. This relationship is then clarified as 変らない. In other words, `the relationship between 'rich lifestyle' and 'current lifestyle' is 'nothing different'`.

Comment: So it's 'comparison' as i thouhgt.
Why doesn't https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A8 mention such definitions?

Comment: Strictly speaking, と is not a comparison marker. It indicates a relationship between two nouns or noun phrases. Sometimes this relationship is a comparison, but sometimes it may not be. It needs a clarifying word (同じ, 変らない, etc) to perform that role. Check 'A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar' p476 for more details. Jisho is a useful dictionary, but it's not an authoritative source for grammatical complexities.