# Alguém poderia me explicar o uso da partícula の e do と nessa frase?

Tags: particle-の

> 日本の学生の多くは、18歳になるとこれまでの環境と大きく変わります。

Eu percebi que tem alguns substantivos que precisam ser usados juntamente com o の na frase, mas as vezes não sei se é preciso ser antes ou depois. Por exemplo, 環境の ou の環境. E no caso do と, eu acho que está sendo usado por causa do 変わります.

**English** (courtesy of Google Translate)

I noticed that there are some nouns that need to be used together with the の in the sentence, but sometimes I don't know if it needs to be before or after. For example, 環境の or の環境. And in the case of と, I think it's being used because of 変わります.

Comment: 「日本の学生の多くは、18歳になるとこれまでの環境と大きく変わります。」← なんかあんまり美しくない日本語… 「これまでの環境と変わる」の主語は「日本の学生の多く」じゃないし。。

Comment: @Chocolate I thought it felt a little odd but I wasn't at all sure. How would you fix the sentence?

Comment: @user3856370 「日本の学生の多くは、18歳になると**環境が** （それまでとは）大きく変わります。」とかですかね～

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 日本の学生の多くは、18歳になるとこれまでの環境と大きく変わります。
> For most Japanese students, when they turn eighteen, the environment (they have lived in) up until now changes a lot

これまでの環境 means "the environment up until now". In XのY, X describes Y. The sentence should still make sense if you remove Xの. For example, removing これまでの gives: ...18歳になると環境と大きく変わります "... when they turn eighteen the environment changes a lot", but removing の環境 gives a meaningless sentence: ".. when they turn eighteen the up until now changes a lot".

I'm surprised you asked about これまでの環境. For me the more confusing part is 日本の学生の多く. I'm a little unsure here so some confirmation from a more experienced speaker would be useful. I think 日本の学生の多く and 多くの日本の学生 are both valid. 多くの日本の学生 Would mean "many Japanese students" and we can certainly remove 多くの and leave a valid sentence: "Japanese students, when they turn 18 ...". With 日本の学生の多く I think it better translates as "most Japanese students" and again I could remove 日本の学生の to get "Most, when they turn 18 ...", though there would have to be previous context for you to know who 'most' was referring to.

Finally, the と in これまでの環境と大きく変わります. The  stripped down sentence would be 環境と変わります. This と is a particle marking a comparison. It is comparing これまでの環境 (the environment up until now) with an inferred new environment and saying that there is a change. Perhaps [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/78819/7944) explains it better than I can.

**Edit**

Note that the translations offered above are rather loose. As discussed in the comments the subject of 変わります should be the environment of the student before they turn 18, but this is omitted from the sentence. To be clear, the phrase marked with と is the thing that is being compared against and not the thing that changes. The full structure should be XがYと変わります -- X changes compared to Y. But Xが (the previous environment) has been omitted. This makes the original sentence rather clunky.

Comment: It is comparing an inferred **new** environment, which is the missing subject, with これまでの環境 (the environment up until now). 環境と変わります alone makes little sense.

Comment: @aguijonazo Doh! Fixed now. Regarding chocolate's comment about it not being beautiful Japanese, is there a simple fix? Just how bad is the sentence? It feels a bit off to me, but I have nowhere near the skill needed be confident in fixing it.

Comment: It's not saying there **has been** a change. It's saying the environment changes when they become 18, compared to the environment up till then. The sentence doesn't say **what** changes and only says the redundant "compared to ..." part. 18歳になると**環境が**大きく変わります would have been enough. The choice of **これ**まで is also bizarre.

Comment: @aguijonazo Sorry, I was being way too loose with the English when I said "has been". Not a good thing to do when I'm trying to explain grammar. Fixed that and added a section highlighting the points you brought up. Hope it's better now. I haven't addressed the part about これまで. I don't understand why this is weird.