What is use of と here
彼女が私と同じくらい背が高いんだ
(My girlfriend is about the same height as me.)
Can any one pls explain me how と fits here in this sentence.

Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/71742/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57077/9831

It really helped , thankyou

“〜と” is very often used to link comparatives. One can see this as a distinct usage of “〜と” compared to the “with” function or the quotative function. “Xと同じ” [the same as X], “Xと比べて” [compared to X], “Xと違う” [different from X” and many more are all common patterns.

Thanks , I get it now
